# How to keep the format of a H3 style

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following code which styles an H3 like a header in a page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="divSitMain" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <div class="clsSitMain">
        <h3>Sites</h3>
        <div class="clsLBHolder">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbSit" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Which displays the following:

[image]

I have another similar code as above where I want to add a `+` sign/image for the user to click on and do something, so I modified the code to be this:

```
<div id="divEntMain">
    <div class="clsEntMain">
        <!--<h3>Entities</h3>-->
        <div id="spnEntMainHdr">
            <span id="spnEntMainText">Entities</span>
            <span id="spnEntMainPlus">+</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clsLBHolder">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbEnt" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which displays the following:

[image]

Here is the `CSS` for both codes above:

```
#spnEntMainHdr
{
    background: #BC1C4A;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 90%;
}
#spnEntMainText
{
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    background: #BC1C4A;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#spnEntMainPlus
{
    float: right;
}
.clsSitMain h3
{
    background: #DC522B;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}
#divEntMain, #divSitMain
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#lbEnt, #lbSit
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clsLBHolder
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #4800ff;
}
#lbEnt {
    color: #BC1C4A;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
}
#lbSit
{
    color: #DC522B;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
}
```

How can I fix it so that I am able to add the `+` sign/image to the right of the header with the same padding?

Updated issue:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to keep the format of H3 is to use H3.

```
    <h3 id="spnEntMainHdr">
        <span id="spnEntMainText">Entities</span>
        <span id="spnEntMainPlus">+</span>
    </h3>
```

Comment: And then use float for each span? Didn't know if it was normal to use HTML tags inside the H3 itself... I will give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same issue IE8... Same thing in Chrome and FF as well.

Comment: You don't need to float SPANS - they're already inline elements. You may want to set the H3 to position:relative, and use position:absolute on the plus sign, set top:5px;right:5px and give it a go.

Comment: It isn't working as the header is too small in padding

Comment: jsfiddle.net - post your current test, then post the URL here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JeL9P/1/ I updated and as you can see it doesn't stretch all the way

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand the issue right - you want to set your spans ad proper left and right padding.

The problem is -  tag is displayed inline. For example - a  is displayed as a block. So either you change your spans to divs or you set display:block; for them.

The next thing - in css, you set the padding of the parent #spnEntMainHdr to "13px 20px"
and then you set them back to 0. Why ?

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/2L3mu/) a little fiddle I made with your code.
Check out the changes in css and the result.

```
#spnEntMainHdr
{
    background: #BC1C4A;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    /* margin: 0; */
    /* padding: 0; */
    width: 90%;
    height:20px;
}
#spnEntMainText
{
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    background: #BC1C4A;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    display:block;
    /* padding: 13px 20px; */
    /* margin: 0; */
    /* padding: 0; */
}
#spnEntMainPlus
{
    float: right;
    display:block;
}
.clsSitMain h3
{
    background: #DC522B;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}
#divEntMain, #divSitMain
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#lbEnt, #lbSit
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clsLBHolder
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #4800ff;
}
#lbEnt {
    color: #BC1C4A;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
}
#lbSit
{
    color: #DC522B;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some code in the code block that I started above.  Answers including jsfiddle links cannot be accepted unless if they also contain code (or unless you go around site rules which is not a good idea)

Comment: I was able to follow the link and adjusted but for some reason it is coming out bigger and wider than the other header. I updated my question with the screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot in my question which I just updated shows how it is looking now after I used the code from your JSFiddle.